# random Application suspended for half a second when Windows XP (32bit, SP3) plays a sound

Tags: c++, windows-xp, multicore

I noticed that the executation of different programs is sometimes delayed for half a second when windows plays a sound on (at least my) multi core machines (not in a virtual box). I tested 3 different computer hardware configurations. Also I have written a small c++ test application to recreate this problem. It just calculates some megabytes of nonsense in the memory and outputs the time, that was spended for this. This is done in a loop, so you continously get outputs. I uploaded this test program (including source code for self compilation, e.g. with GCC 4.7.2 from MinGW, if you fear malware in the executable) to here: http://daiw.de/share/PrintCalculationTimes.zip

On the following screenshots you can see what happens when a sound is played (via the sound settings in the control panel) while the program is executed:
http://daiw.de/share/PrintCalculationTimesWithoutSound.png

http://daiw.de/share/PrintCalculationTimesWithSoundWithAnnotations.png
(It does not happen with every click on the play button, but with multiple clicks it is quite easy to reproduce on my test PCs.)

Is this a well known problem? Can someone confirm this observation with the test case I provided?

Thanks for your attention.

Dobi

Comment: There is a security feature in newer versions of windows.  When windows asks you for permission to do something sensitive, it suspends all threads so a hacker's program can not try to answer the dialog for you.  Does not sounds like what you are seeing.

Answer (score 3):

What I see is a 16ms jitter, not half a second delay. Also, I see it independently of any sounds being played (even in your screenshot this seems to be the case).

It would truly surprise me if playing some sounds prevented a (non-background-priority) thread from running, too. That would be a serious problem for literally thousands of computer games, all of which require both fluid animation and playing sounds all the time.

Considering that 16ms is the default resolution of the timer you use on your system, the result isn't surprising at all. It's just what you have to expect.

If anything, try using `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` instead, or put a `timeBeginPeriod(1)` at the beginning of your program (needs `-lwinmm`).

(Note that `timeBeginPeriod(1)` makes the scheduler execute more often *globally*, not only in your program, and not only for the lifetime of your program. If you use a laptop and run on battery, you may want to reboot after testing to conserve battery. Normally, one would reset to normal using `endTimePeriod(1)`, but since killing the process is the only way of ending your program that won't work.)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. timeBeginPeriod(1) did not change anything here and the high_resolution_clock only made the 500ms from the second screenshot ([link](http://daiw.de/share/PrintCalculationTimesWithSoundWithAnnotations.png) visible even more precisely. Time resolution is not the problem. Btw. My test machines have varying hardware components but are all from the save manufacturer (Fujitsu). Perhaps it is a driver or hardware issue. And maybe games are mostly not affected, because it only happens with PlaySound calls, not with modern sound APIs. I don't know.

Comment: I could very well imagine a _small_ stall if a driver or realtime priorty task has its affinity restricted to a particular core (many people still "solve" multi-core issues simply by setting affinity to CPU0, even nowadays) and your process incidentailly runs on the same core at that time. In that case, the OS would preempt your thread in favour of the higher-priority one, and eventually (at the next scheduler tick) move it to another free core. That might cause additional delay from cache misses. Obviously, this can be nowhere near half a second, though. What you see is very weird.